# Does QWOP have an ending?

Tags: qwop

I've been struggling with QWOP for the past hour and have finally grown weary of trying to get my character to awkwardly throw his legs outwards while remaining somewhat upright. Can I actually finish the 100m track, or does it carry on forever?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

QWOP has an ending.

> It also has two boss fights!
>
>  The first boss fight appears at the 50m mark and will surprise you completely when you first encounter it.  It's easier than it looks though, a straight kick will assure victory.
>
>  The final boss appears at the 100m mark and you probably won't win but you can't lose either.
>
>  There are ways to ensure victory, such as getting into a low position where you can slowly twitch your way to the finish line, but it's easier to just watch the online videos.

Comment: Wow...is this for real?  I need to play this game again if this is in fact real now.

Comment: AFAIK, always has been real! Well, as 'real' as QWOP can be.  It's a very difficult ending to reach, but it's there.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it ends.  From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QWOP):

> When the player has successfully reached 50 meters they must jump a hurdle, and at 100 meters the player is encouraged to perform a long jump, although simply passing the finish line is sufficient to complete the game.

Comment: Dude! Spoilers!  8 )

Comment: Most annoying part is that I can't edit in a spoiler tag because it's only one character long.

Comment: @Matt Sorry about the edit, maaan. Out of curiosity, why don't you want the spoiler block?

Comment: Maybe I've missed some Meta discussions on this, but the title question is clearly asking for this "spoiler" (which is not a spoiler at all).  Users who don't want to see the answer shouldn't look at the question, they shouldn't be protected as if they were selectively illiterate (can read my answer, but not the question).

Comment: True. There's a meta-conversation [going on](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1859/proper-usage-of-spoiler-tag) about the proper usage of this tag right now, actually; this might be a point to be raised there.

Comment: The discussion Mana is referring to is [this one](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1859/proper-usage-of-spoiler-tag), which is about the tag itself rather than spoiler blocks. Personally, I think the "yes" answer has no need to be hidden. You don't actually have any of the ending's "content", so to speak, but I'm neutral on whether or not the quote gets hidden.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I've posted my thoughts over there.

Comment: I was just trying to be funny, I'm quite surprised at how seriously everyone took it.  We are talking QWOP after all.

Comment: @Task Yep, I got sucked straight from "lolwut" to ["well, actually..."](http://trollcats.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/well_actually_trollcat.jpg)